# Is there currently a consensus on which api design fits a react/redux app?

Tags: reactjs, odata, redux, api-design, json-api

I'm building a single-page application with react and redux. Which of course needs a backend for its data. Now we're looking at what api architecture would be best, but it I couldn't find any consensus on which api architecture would best fit a react/redux application.

Now I know that you can basically consume data any way you like. But still there are clear market leaders, like redux over mobx for example. That doesn't make them better, but it's nice to at least know where the preference lies.

So my question is: which api architecture is used most for a react/redux app at this point in time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our experience, it's best not to make the API "fit" react/redux and vice versa.
Just use thunk-action-creators and handle the API calls in whatever shape or form they are.

Here is a contrived example:

```
export function getUserById (userId) {
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_USER_BY_ID', payload: userId })
        try {
            const user = await api.get(`/users/${userId}`)
            ga('send', 'event', 'user', 'profile', 'view')

            dispatch({
                type: 'LOAD_USER',
                payload: user
            })

            dispatch({
                type: 'NOTIFY_SUCCESS',
                payload: `Loaded ${user.firstname} ${user.lastname}!`
            })
        }
        catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: 'NOTIFY_ERROR',
                payload: `Failed to load user: ${err.message}`,
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest benefit of this approach is flexibility.
The API(s) stay completely unopinionated about the consumer.
You can handle errors, add retry logic, fallback logic differently on any page.
Easy to glue together actions that require calls to several different apis in parallel or sequential.

We tried many approaches like "redux over the wire" and relays/apollos "bind component to query".
This one stuck as the most flexible and easiest to understand and refactor.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to find authoritative information or guidelines on this subject, but it's hard to argue that if you create an API specifically for one flux/redux app, and you store the data in normalized form in the database, it's rather silly to de-normalize it in your API endpoint only to normalize it straight after in your client (using [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr))... In that case, just leave the data normalized and pass it over the wire to your client like that.

Concretely you'd have something like this:

`GET /meetings`

```
{
    "result": ["1", "2"],
    "entities": {
        "meetings": {
            "1": { "id": 1, "date": "2016-01-01", "attendees": [1, 2, 3] },
            "2": { "id": 2, "date": "2016-01-02", "attendees": [2, 3, 4] }
        },
        "users": {
            "1": { "id": 1, "name": "User 1" },
            "2": { "id": 1, "name": "User 2" },
            "3": { "id": 1, "name": "User 3" },
            "4": { "id": 1, "name": "User 4" }
        }
    }
}
```

Given that each of these entities correspond to a property on your state, such response is [trivial to merge into your store](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UpdatingNormalizedData.html) in a reducer action, using something like [Lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge):

```
return _.merge({}, state, action.entities);
```

If you have multiple consumers, you might opt for a `normalize=true` query parameter. You might also want to combine this with some kind of `expand|include=entities,to,include` query parameter.

Finally, note that the JSON API spec [doesn't play nicely](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/jsonapi.md) with the normalized structure of flux/redux stores.

Further reading:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/323325/how-to-structure-a-rest-api-response-for-a-flux-redux-frontend
- https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/5g3rht/use_normalizr_or_just_flatten_in_the_rest_api/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, there's so much new technology. There isn't really a consensus on what to choose to use, like it was back in the day. Don't find an architecture that would be a best fit for a react/redux application. Find an architecture that best FITS YOUR PROJECT.

Comment: I was expecting that answer, and of course I'm trying to do that. But there's value in knowing which architecture gets the most use. It's a good starting point, and usually it gets the most usage because it does something right.

Comment: Got it, follow this link to check out some diagrams https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/653, view -> action -> dispatch -> reducer -> state change, is what redux is doing for our state management. I would also recommend checking out the Ducks file structure for redux here: https://medium.com/@scbarrus/the-ducks-file-structure-for-redux-d63c41b7035c#.q8ukk13qg

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I meant. I meant which restful json api architecture (or standard, such as odata or jsonapi.org) is most commonly used in combination with a react/redux app.